# Why, when using SSIS from the SSMS (TASK/IMPORT) are Triggers not activated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssms

I've started using SSIS from within the SSMS (right-clicking the database / TASKS / IMPORT).  It works great, especially when uploading to a server that has a high ping time and INSERT INTO statements take an (extremely) excessive time.

The problem I've encountered, is that the INSERT triggers are not activated.  How can I ensure they are?  I have limited rights to the server and cannot (currently) save the SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are not activated because the tasks in SSIS are bulk operations.

Comment: Is there any way to make such an operation activate  trigger?

Comment: You would have to edit the ssis packages generated by ssms not to use "Fast Load" - i think that is the main trigger to run bulk load. However speed will drop drastically without bulk load, as you're doing insert into row by row.